# How does LSTM convert character embedding vectors to sentence vector for sentence classification?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I want to build a LSTM model for sentence classification using character embeddings.

I know how to do it using word embeddings where the model can learn the embeddings from word indexes but not sure how to do it with character embeddings.

**for word embeddings:**

```
sentence_list = ['this is a dog', 'the cat and the mouse']
label = [1,0]
word_dict = {'this':1,
             'is':2,
             'a':3,
             'dog':4,
             'the':5,
             'cat':6,
             'and':7,
             'mouse':8}

# set vector length = 9
vectors = [[1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,0]
              [0,0,0,0,5,6,7,5,8]]
model.fit(vectors,label)
```

so this is ready to be fitted into a LSTM model.

How do we do it for character based vectors?

for example:
if i have this character dictionary:

```
 char_dict = {'t':1,
             'h':2,
             'i':3,
             's':4,
             'a':5,
             'd':6,
             'o':7,
             'g':8}
```

How do i format this to be readable for the LSTM classification model?
More specifically, how do we combine multiple character vectors to be fed into the LSTM model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly the same. No difference at all.

Transform the sentences into vectors of indices and go fit.

**Important things**:

Don't make sentences starting with 0, your `vectors` should be:

```
vectors = [[1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,0]
          [5,6,7,5,8,0,0,0,0]]
```

Have indices for spaces (at least) and punctuation:

```
 char_dict = {'t':1,
         'h':2,
         'i':3,
         's':4,
         'a':5,
         'd':6,
         'o':7,
         'g':8
         ' ':9,
         '.':10,
         'c':11}

sentences = ['this is a dog', 'that is a cat.']
vectors = [
              [char_dict[ch] for ch in sentence] for sentence in sentences
          ]

vectors = [
              [1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 3, 4, 9, 5,  9, 6, 7,  8],
              [1, 2, 5, 1, 9, 3, 4, 9, 5, 11, 5, 1, 10]
          ]
```